# Magento Stock Management Error

Tags: php, magento, stock

I am running an online store which is built in Magento.
**Sometimes when customer place order then inventory goes to -(negative) values.**
So I just wanted to know, in which possible cases, inventory can be a negative value.

So I can figure out any solution for that..

Answer (score 0):

For this can you please check your admin configuration :

Go to admin > System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Option > find "**Backorders**" Option > Allow QTY below 0

Set to **No BackOreder**.

Answer (score 0):

Goto system->configuration->catalog->productstock option->managestock->no

If its set to no, please do yes.